# How to use a credit card as T-Money?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, south-korea

According to [this post](http://www.straitstimes.com/asia/card-not-cash-is-king-in-south-korea), it seems that you can use your credit card as T-money, and just tap your card on the subway gate to pass it through.

> Much like Singapore's ez-link card, T-money is a rechargeable stored-value card with a smart chip for fare deduction. The chip has been modified to fit credit cards, debit cards and even mobile phone SIM cards - which means people can tap their phones to take the bus.

It is amazing. I want to use my credit card as T-money.

However, how can I do it? My guess is that you must get issued a card in the first place that is compatible with T-Money; at least that is the case in Japan, where there is a credit card issued by JR-East which is compatible with Suica.

Or if this is the case in Singapore, you can link your credit card to your transportation card (ez-link), and top up your ez-link automatically when the balance runs out.

So is it possible to get issued the card? I can stay for a few months if it is needed, though I enter it with 90 days of free-visa requirement.

I don't mind what brand it is (though UnionPay or MasterCard is preferable as I don't have it), or don't need much limit. All the things I need is to get through the gate when I don't have enough balance on T-Money.

Comment: Technically, that description makes absolutely no sense, which is normal for news stories about technology... Strangely, Wikipedia gives no description of the tech.

Comment: "which is normal for news stories about technology" so true, @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 1):

These are RFID cards (sometimes referred to as NFC, although technically the two are different). They consist of two parts - an interrogator (the reader) and the tagged device (in this case, the card).

The same technology is used in Dubai for the public transportation system; and is available in most mobile phones.

You get a special SIM which is encoded with a NFC tag; you still need NFC technology on your phone; with the exception of iPhones (which have NFC technology, but is only accessible to Apply Pay); most modern phones are compatible.

Here is a [page on du, a mobile operator in the UAE](http://www.du.ae/personal/mobile/pay-with-du/rta-smart-nol) that has some more details.

For the credit/debit cards, it is the same idea - except the tag is embedded in the debit/credit card. Your card must support this; and the technology is marketed as MasterCard Contactless (used to be called Paypass), Visa calls it payWave, and American Express calls it ExpressPay.

Specifically for T-money it is an embedded RFID device, which is also available as a SIM card and a phone application. However, you cannot use your credit card as t-money cards; you can get a refillable t-money card (its called the City Pass Plus Card), and you can reload it via a debit/credit card.

Just like the normal (non-reloadable) t-money cards, this one also never expires you can buy one and use it for your subsequent visits.

You can find out more information on t-money at [this website](http://eng.koreasmartcard.com/jsp/newpub/oversea/english/t-money/T_what.jsp).